# how to pass a png texture created in managed Unity code, and render it from inside a c++ plugin?

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, plugins

If I load a png sprite file from Unity (via Resources.Load()), how do I pass sprite.texture to a c++ plugin code and render it with OpenGL? I tried passing sprite.texture.GetNativeTexturePtr() to the native code then use glBindTexture and glDrawArrays to draw the texture, but it shows nothing on the screen. It shows a rectangle in the correct place when I disable the texture, but nothing shows when I enable texture.

(the Unity example project for native rendering plugin does not pass the texture data, but rather creating the data inside the plugin.)

Native code snippet:

```
 glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
 glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
 glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

 GLuint texID = (GLuint)(size_t)(texturePtr); // texID from GetNativeTexturePtr.
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID); 
 glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

 const float verts[] = {x, y, x+w, y, x, y+h, x+w, y+h};
 const float texCoords[] = {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1};

 glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0,verts);
 glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
```

Comment: just out of curiosity why would you want to do this when the whole point of using unity is to avoid doing this

Comment: It is very hard to help you in this case.You show only one side of your problem.The other side is Unity native plugin API + Unity C# layer.I can just tell you that the right way is to use GetNativeTexturePtr.I did something similar and it worked.In your cases there are too many unknowns,because of which it is hard to say where is the problem.

Comment: @ina that's a question i asked myself before i tried this approach, and i think Unity approach to render each sprite on a separate game object is too cumbersome and costly for some type of games, like isometric city building, which needs to maintain sorting on large number of objects and also be able to render multiple sprites on each object efficiently. So, I am trying to blit the texture manually on the screen, to have more control with custom rendering method. alternatively, of course we can use another game engine other than unity which has a more conventional render method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old but for anyone having graphics problems in the future:

- Keep in mind which rendering engine (OpenGL, DirectX) the data was created in
- Also the context the image was created and rendered in; Unity has multiple contexts so this can get tricky. (Still haven't figured out context situation with multiple monitors)
- Don't forget you still need a shader to render; I didn't see any calls to that stuff

. Here's an example:

```
// Somewhere in your loading code //

// create shader program from source string
g_Program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(g_Program, g_VertexShader);
glAttachShader(g_Program, g_FragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(g_Program);
GLint status = 0;
glGetProgramiv(g_Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
assert(status == GL_TRUE);

g_UniformFrame = glGetUniformLocation(g_Program, "texture");

// Somewhere in your rendering code //

// use our shader program
glUseProgram(g_Program);

// bind our geometry
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VertexBuffer);

// bind our texture.GetNativeTexturePtr()
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *(GLuint *)cur_RT);
glUniform1i(g_UniformFrame, 0);

// Draw quad
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```